# MySQL Sleeping Threads Eating up all my Connections

Tags: php, mysql, connection

I've been continually getting "Too many connections" errors on my site which uses php and mysql. In looking at information from mytop (show processlist), I find that nearly all of these connections are just sleeping ones. I tried setting mysql settings interactive_timeout and wait_timeout to 120 seconds but some processes are still somehow sleeping for longer than that. My php max_execution_time is set to 30 seconds so why would any script keep the mysql connection open for more than 30 seconds? I am not explicitly calling mysql_close in any of my scripts and I'm not using pconnect. Do you have any suggestions or advice on what I need to do or look at? Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Try adding explicit `mysql_close($conn)` or the relevant function for your particular driver to the scripts you're using to see if it's that PHP is failing to kill the connections.